# Adobe Flash Air application publishing error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cc

When i'm trying to publish my app for Air from Adobe Flash CC , i'm getting this error all the time:

> Error creating files. aapt tool
>   failed:C:\Users....\AndroidManifest.xml: error: Unable to open file
>   for read. No such file or directory

How can i get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case while developing AIR applications for Android via IntelliJ Idea
The message appears while trying to compile a project.

I found it to be caused by a setting in "Run/Debug Configurations" -> "Options" -> Debug device over: Network | USB Port.

Switching to Network rather then USB Port (even if device is actually connected via USB) for me fixes the issue.

If you are using the flash IDE, whether CC or Flash Pro 6,
you might want to try change settings in:

"Publish Settings" -> "Player Settings" (for the AIR SDK) ->

which opens up a dialog name "AIR for Android Settings".

Select the "Deployment" (tab) -> "Android Deployment" -> "Wireless Network Connection" (and not the "Default" option)

The default option causes the same error you've mentioned while selecting:
"Wireless Network connection" Should Work, as i tested in both cases.

Comment: It looks like there is no Solution to it currently, as i'm still having this issue,
and my workaround is just publish again, once it works and once it doesn't - so it looks like a problem with cache management somewhere deep inside the Air SDK while compiling....